# How to install system trusted CA certificate on Android without rooting

Tags: rooting, lock-screens, system, certificates

I need to install the firewall certificate on the devices of my company. Since I can't install a system trusted certificate without rooting the device I thought of creating an Android image that comes with the certificate and flash it into the devices, but...

Where or how should I put such cert on the image? Or if there is another solution that also doesn't envolves rooting I would be happy to hear!

Comment: Are you sure root is needed? I don't think so. I have Adguard which is adblock +firewall and it installs certificates without root. Question marked as duplicate deals with earlier version of Android but even on 8.1 you can install similarly (security & location >encryption and credentials

Comment: As far as I have seen you can add user certificates without root, no?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by giving the example of Adguard app